# Wcf service exception "The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme"

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-4.5

I am getting an exception at client side while processing  from an out side vendor wcf service like `"The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Basic'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm="CASM"'".`
I am requesting large datas from webservice some point of time i am getting exception.Intersting thing is i am getting some data from wcf service and after that getting exception.So i assume whether i need to fine tune the request?? so i should not ask large data at a time or it is some thing a different issue. I did like the post shown "[Error when adding web service reference in VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19433452/error-when-adding-web-service-reference-in-vs2012)"  but no luck.
Can anybody tell me what all are the possible reason behind this exception. Below is my webconfig part and i am suing username and password in my code

```
<binding name="Test" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
      receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
      bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="6553600" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="6553600"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="Basic"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  <endpoint address="http://testurl/as" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="Test" contract="Testservice.Test" name="Test">
  </endpoint>
```

UPDATE

one more thing what is this `realm="CASM"` in exception , i am not able to set in client config, intellisense is not giving

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this

```
 <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="Basic"
      realm="" />
    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
  </security>
```

with this line

```
<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
   <transport clientCredentialType="Anonymous"/>
   <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
</security>
```

Comment: I did this, even i posted same link in my question

Comment: How are calling the service using WSDL or httpwebrequest??

Comment: i used wsdl to call webservice ,to create proxy.I am doing my own xmlserialization of each request and respone.May be something goes wrong there?but interseting thing is i am getting some data s from webservice

Comment: try to get rid of all of this 
`closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
      receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
      bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="6553600" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="6553600"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />`

Comment: no luck as of now ,do i need to put some delays in bindings of webconfig

Comment: Try to increase the timeout since you are dealing with Large data it may be the problem actually

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74275/discussion-between-coder1409-and-peter).